# gradle: compileJava? Found module. compileTestJava? Module foo not found?

Tags: java, gradle, java-module

I'm building a project with quite a few sub projects.  Each one is a module.

With one of those subprojects in particular, I'm getting:

> Task :foo:compileTestJava FAILED
>
> error: module not found: foo
>
> 1 error

Note that both `compileJava` and `classes` (and an empty `processResources` if we must be pedantic) both completed successfully.

The `build.gradle` for this subproject is trivial:

```
ext.someVar = 'someValue'
dependencies {
   compile project(':some.other.subproject.used.in.lots.of.other.places1')
   compile project(':some.other.subproject.used.in.lots.of.other.places2')
}
```

That's it.  Yes, these subprojects have been used together in some of those `lots.of.other.places`.

The main project has a highly non-trival `build.gradle`.  It has an extensive `subprojects {}`, much of which is a `test {}`.  This section of the build works just fine for the other 10+ subprojects.  What it does not have is anything that treats individual subprojects differently.  It does not have a custom `compileTest`, and `ext.someVar` is used in path construction, not conditions.

I get the same output when I run gradle (5.2.1) either from within IDEA or from the command line.

`gradlew --console verbose` just made the output prettier.

`gradlew -d` added quite a bit of noise, but no new signal:

I've run `gradlew clean compileTestJava` (many times).  No change.

I've manually deleted the `.gradle` folder, then run.  No change.

I ran with `-s`, and it gave me this:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':foo:compileTestJava'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$2.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$2.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:117)
        at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:184)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveIncrementalChangesTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveIncrementalChangesTaskExecuter.java:84)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:74)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:109)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:93)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:45)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:94)
```

What could have gone wrong here?  Where else can I look for a cause?

Comment: so the includes are  added to `settings.gradle`?

Comment: Yep.  When I remove `include 'foo'`, everything is fine.  With it: one inexplicable error.

Comment: It could be that somewhere in your dependencies, you are depending on `foo` rather than `:foo`.